# Post to RESTful web service

Tags: xmlhttprequest, vb6, http-post

I have this code but i cant seem to get around how to use same code with body parameters. I have to add two body parameters of number = 123456 and first_name = james. Please help update the following code to allow that and work within VB6.

```
Dim sUrl As String
Dim response As String
Dim xmlhttp

Set sUrl = "http://my.domain.com/service/operation/param"

Set xmlhttp = Server.CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP")
xmlhttp.open "POST", sURL, False
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
xmlhttp.send()

Dim response As String = xmlhttp.responseText

Set xmlhttp = Nothing
```

Comment: REST APIs do not use Form encoded data.  It looks like you are trying to scrape a user-facing web page.

Comment: You typically pass these parameters as a parameter in the `.Send()` method, e.g. `.Send("number=123456&first_name=james")`. But without knowing the actual definition of that API, it's hard to tell.